# JQuery uploadify error only on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, uploadify

[image: Error Only On IE]

Hi Buddies,

I got the error when I use uploadify only on IE.

the following is my setting

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="uploadify/jquery.uploadify.js"></script>

  $('#upload-upload').uploadify({
        'uploader': 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script': 'Upload.ashx',
        'cancelImg': 'images/close.png',
        'auto': false,
        'multi': true,
        'queueSizeLimit': 4,
        'sizeLimit': 36700160, //35 MB
        //'sizeLimit': 4000000,        
        'buttonImg': 'images/Choose-File.png',
        'width': 83,
        'height': 23,
        'rollover': true,
        'displayData': 'speed',
        'folder': '/uploads',
        'onQueueFull': function (event, queueSizeLimit) {

        },
        //'onSelectOnce': function (event, data) {

        //},
        'onAllComplete': function (event, data) {
           //Code
        }
    });
```

and then I called

```
$('#upload-upload').uploadifyUpload();
```

Comment: Could you maybe show your mark–up for this section? Especially the form you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/methods/uploadifysettings/) states that when you are changing the `scriptData` in `uploadifySettings` that you need to add a third parameter to clear the existing `scriptData` object.

Change

```
$('#upload-upload').uploadifySettings('scriptData', { 'uploadid': temp.uploadid, 'userid': temp.userid });
```

to

```
$('#upload-upload').uploadifySettings('scriptData', { 'uploadid': temp.uploadid, 'userid': temp.userid }, true);
```

Not sure if this is your problem, but at least your call will then follow the documentation.